# why does the value function often have the same functional form as the instantaneous target function?

Tags: optimal-control, dynamic-programming

If we want to maximize $$\sum _{t=0}^\infty f(x_t,u_t), \text { s.t. } x_{t+1}=g(x_t,u_t)$$

Then the value function $$V(x_t)=\max_{u_t,u_{t+1},...}\sum _{t=0}^\infty f(x_t,u_t)$$

Often has approximately the same functional form as $f$.

For example, in a problem I was working on, $f$ had the form $\ln u_t$, and $V(x_t)$ had the form $A+B\ln(x_t)$

**What is the reason that the value function often has the same functional form as the instantaneous target function $f$?**

Comment: This result is proved only for the case of linear dynamics and a quadratic cost function. That is, if you have $f(x,u)=x^TQx+u^TRu$, then $V(x)=x^TPx$, where $P$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix (which may depend on $t$ under circumstances). For other cases, there are no proven results, but it is rather common to guess the form of the value function (so called ansatz). In particular, you can guess that $V(x)$ is of form $A+B\ln(x)$. As long as it works it's fine, but there is no guarantee that this will work in general.

Comment: Do you know why this is the case for linear dynamics and quadratic cost? Or do you know of a theorem?

Comment: You might look at this paper https://doi.org/10.1016/0005-1098(77)90017-6. I do not have an access to it right now, but I recall that there was quite a lot of related stuff.